# Is it possible to populate additional fields with a json object for Mongo java?

Tags: java, mongodb, mongo-java

I know there is a BasicDBObject that allows you do go:

```
BasicDBObject info = new BasicDBObject();

info.put("x", 203);
info.put("y", 102);
```

The issue I have is that the value can only be a primitive type.
I have a json object that I want to store with the common data that I am unable to modify, but would like to describe json object in a single mongo document. What can I do in order to do something like:

```
BasicDBObject info = new BasicDBObject();
info.put("Name", "John");
info.put("Main Hobby", "Hiking");
info.put("Albums", json-string-with-nested-arrays);
```

To sum up, I am looking for a way to allow me to store both a json object in addition to key value pairs in the same document (assume that the "json-string-with-nested-arrays" I have is not modifiable, so I cannot insert additional attributes into it.) How can I accomplish this?

Below is the json-string-with-nested-arrays:

```
{"data":[{"stuff":[
    {"onetype":[
        {"id":1,"name":"John Doe"},
        {"id":2,"name":"Don Joeh"}
    ]},
    {"othertype":[
        {"id":2,"company":"ACME"}
    ]}]
},{"otherstuff":[
    {"thing":
        [[1,42],[2,2]]
    }]
}]}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If **"json-string-with-nested-arrays"** is a JSON string then you can do something like this in mongo-java-driver.

```
info.put("Albums", JSON.parse(json-string-with-nested-arrays));
```

This `JSON.parse()` method is part of mongo-java-driver

Comment: json-string-with-nested-arrays has to be perfectly formatted Json String

Comment: Not functioning correctly as it only stores the JSON object as a string and not a JSON object.

Comment: I don't thinks so. JSON.parse() method converts JSON String to mongo compatible JSON. I could not get how come this can happen.I'm able to use this perfectly fine

Comment: If you do an ajax call using jsonp or json, you will notice that the value for the key "Albums" is a string(of the json object).

Comment: Can you show me the your `json-string-with-nested-arrays`? And what's the `Accept` request header when you make Ajax call

Comment: Client-Side ajax call accept: jsonp, headers application-x/javascript. I have added the json-string-with-nested-arrays to my original post.

Comment: are you sure json-string-with-nested-arrays is `instaceof` string ??

Comment: http://www.mkyong.com/mongodb/java-mongodb-insert-a-document/ and see section **JSON parse example**, you will realize how this works.